# allowing only super user login

Tags: django, django-admin

I have written a django page that requires only super users to login. So I have added

```
foo_view = staff_member_required(foo_view)
```

but it doesn't cut, now I can control only allowing staff marked users to login but this doesn't cut. I have tried something like

```
def foo_view(request):
       if not request.user.is_superuser:
           #render some "not allowed page"
       #else render the page
```

but it doesn't seem to help as giving me errors.

Comment: What errors is your second code snippet giving you?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def foo_view(request):
    # ...
foo_view = user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)(foo_view)
```

Or (with Python >= 2.4):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def foo_view(request):
    # ...
```

Comment: @Dominic I tried to use user_passes_test, however this results in a redirect loop. Seems like it's redirecting the request to the login screen again and again as the logged-in user is not the super user.

Answer (score 4):

The code you suggested works perfect for me, I used it in many projects since Django 1.4:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse

@login_required
def foo_view(request):
   if not request.user.is_superuser:
       return HttpResponse('The user is not superuser')

   # Do whatever you need to do
```

This code works perfect for me since Django 1.4 to 1.7 at least.

Answer (score 0):

Above answers seems to be for very early versions of django. They are bit complicated than for the more later version

for django 1.11 here is a bit similar but simpler strategy.
click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47689629/7950499)