# How to limit a view to superuser only?

Tags: django

**view.py**

```
@login_required
@permission_required('is_superuser')
def score_reset(request):
   pass
```

**url.py**

```
url(r'^score-reset/$', score_reset, name='score-reset'),
```

I have the following code and to my surprise I still hit the function, despite being logged in with a non superuser. I was expecting to get a permission denied.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`is_superuser` isn't a permission, it's an attribute on the user model. Django already has another [decorator you can make use of called `user_passes_test`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L14) to perform this check:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def score_reset(self,...):
    ...
```

- [allowing only super user login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404160/allowing-only-super-user-login)
- [Django is_staff permission decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833184/django-is-staff-decorator-problem)

Comment: btw, I'm not marking this as a duplicate as neither answer I've linked to mention that `user_passes_test` is an existing django decorator as well as the fact that `is_superuser` isn't a permission

Comment: The question asks for restricting to superuser only. The example code should be @user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)

Comment: Using `user_passes_test` [the above snippet] does the work.But you may want to consider that this is will redirect to login page for all non-super users, even if they have already logged in.You may want to write your own decorator to get the job done.

Answer (score 7):

Above answers seems to be for very early versions of django.
They are bit complicated than for the more later version

for django 1.11 here is a bit similar but simpler strategy.

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def some_view(request):
if request.user.is_superuser:
    //allow access only to superuser
    return render(request, 'app/template1.html', args)
else:
    //allow access only to user
    return render(request, 'app/template2.html', args)
```

Answer (score 5):

Make use of Django's [UserPassesTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin)

Create a custom mixin `SuperuserRequiredMixin`

```
#mixins.py
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class SuperuserRequiredMixin(UserPassesTestMixin):
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_superuser
```

Usage

```
class SomeSuperUserOnlyView(SuperuserRequiredMixin, ListView):
    form_class = ExamForm
    template_name = 'exam/newexam.html'
```

Answer (score 2):

@user_passes_test is not an elegant solution if you want to perform this check on many views.
You can easily write your own decorathor having for example @staff_member_require.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46318226/8640093) you can see one of the possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the user passes test decorator to restrict access any way you want. Here is a restriction based on user email example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def email_check(user):
    x = False
    if user.email == 'anyemailhere':
        x = True
    return x

# Create your views here.
@user_passes_test(email_check)
def dash_index(request):
    ...
```

More here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator

Answer (score 0):

**SuperuserRequiredMixin**

Another permission-based mixin. This is specifically for requiring a user to be a superuser. Comes in handy for tools that only privileged users should have access to.

First install: `pip install django-braces`

**views.py**

```
from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin, SuperuserRequiredMixin


class SomeSuperuserView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuperuserRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "path/to/template.html"
```