# blocking unwanted urls in django

Tags: python, django, authentication, url

I have added account app to **installed_apps** in my django project.
also I have added urls of account app as like below:

```
(r"^account/", include("account.urls"))
```

Its working fine.
Now I had to override **SignupView** class of account app. This is also working fine.
Now I have created a new class **CreateUser(SignupView)** and I want that only admin user will be able to create user. So I added a different url for **CreateUser(SignupView)** view. 
Now I want that **account/signup** url with view **SignupView** will not be accessible anymore.

How can I block this particular url by keeping other urls active of account app as this is a library.

Comment: Show your account app `urls.py`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit a view to superuser only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998140/how-to-limit-a-view-to-superuser-only)

Comment: No it does not @lain. Because I dont want to edit library code.

Comment: @Stargazer, here is the urls.py. But I dont want to edit this. Because this is inside a site-packages.

Comment: So wi will need to extend the views and not use the bultin views at all. Override the account urls with your new views.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a specific entry for the one URL that you wish to block **before** you include the packages urls.py. This will take precedence as Django loops over URLs in order looking for the first match

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    path('account/signup', RedirectView.as_view(url='/')),
    path('account', include('account.urls')),
]
```

Comment: I hope this will serve my purpose. Thanks @Iain